# PHP - Check if chosen time is at least 5 minutes into the future

Tags: php, validation, datetime

In the application that I'm working on, the user must choose a date/time which is at least 5 minutes into the future. For this, I'm trying to implement a check. Below is the code which checks the time difference between the current time and chosen time.

```
    $cur_date = new DateTime();
    $cur_date = $cur_date->modify("+1 hours");  //fix the time since its an hour behind
    $cur_date = $cur_date->format('m/d/Y g:i A');


    $to_time = strtotime($chosen_date);
    $from_time = strtotime($cur_date);
    echo round(abs($from_time - $to_time) / 60,2). " minute"; //check the time difference
```

This tells me the time difference from the chosen time and the current time in minutes. So let's say the current time is 09/22/2015 5:53 PM and the chosen time is 09/22/2015 5:41 PM - it will tell me the difference which is 12 minutes.

What I want to know is how I can tell if those 12 minutes are into the future or in the past. I want my application to only proceed if the chosen time is at least 5 minutes into the future.

Comment: Remove the `abs()` and if the result is positive it's in the past.

Comment: Removing abs() made no difference to the output I'm afraid.

Comment: removing abs had to make a difference, if you get negative it means in is in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing too much work. Just use DateTime() to do the date math for you:

```
// Wrong way to do this. Work with timezones instead
$cur_date = (new DateTime()->modify("+1 hours"));

// Assuming acceptable format for $chosen_date
$to_time  = new DateTime($chosen_date);

$diff = $cur_date->diff($to_time);

if ($diff->format('%R') === '-') {
     // in the past
}

echo $diff->format('%i') . ' minutes';
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/437607)

Comment: This code is invalid. If the user inputs tomorow's exact same time it will only display 0 minutes, instead of 1440 (the number of minutes in a day)

Comment: @Salketer their example implies this is not a valid scenario

Answer (score -1):

```
$enteredDate = new DateTime($chosen_date)->getTimestamp();
$now = new DateTime()->getTimestamp();
if(($enteredDate-$now)/60 >=5)echo 'ok';
```

Basically, the code takes the two dates converted in seconds since 1/1/1970. We calculate the difference between the two dates and divide the result by 60 as we want minutes. If there is a difference of at least 5 minutes, we're ok. If the number is negative, then we are in the past.

Comment: There's a problem with this. If the time is in the future it echo's 'ok' but if the date is in the future, let's say next month then it doesn't echo 'ok'.

Comment: I have changed it, using timestamp instead will allow to compare 2 big numbers... DateDiff that I used first would need to test all diff, not just minutes.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is looking to do something similar, I found the Carbon library which is included by default with the framework I am using (Laravel 5), it was much easier to do this calculation.

```
  $chosen_date = new Carbon($chosen_date, 'Europe/London'); 

  $whitelist_date = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
  $whitelist_date->addMinutes(10);

    echo "Chosen date must be after this date: ".$whitelist_date ."</br>";
    echo "Chosen Date: ".$chosen_date ."</br>";

    if ($chosen_date->gt($whitelist_date)) {

        echo "proceed"; 
    } else {
        echo "dont proceed";
    }
```